# Executing a python file in shell that contains whitespace in its name

Tags: shell, whitespace, filenames

I'm in the directory. File name is "Ch2 Quiz"

In conda prompt, I'm typing:

python Quiz Ch2.py

Give error:

python: can't open file 'Quiz': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: `python "Quiz Ch2.py"`.

Comment: You have a valid file name (depending on the filesystem of cause) but you don't have a valid Python module name. This does not matter as long as you don't want to import it but it is a good idea to follow the naming conventions anyway.

Comment: Escape spaces or use tab for auto-completion in bash ```python Quiz\ Ch2.py```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a python question but more like a shell question. You need to pass "Quiz Ch2.py" as one item to the command "python" as its argument.

Usually, a shell will allow any of these:

```
python Quiz\ Ch2.py
python 'Quiz Ch2.py'
python "Quiz Ch2.py"
```

The first one use `\` to escape the space, the second and third one use quote to mean it is one single token although we have a space in it. Some shell will have different interpretation between single and double quote (e.g., if you have a variable resolution it in) but in this simple case. Usually the same.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I'm using the conda prompt, and the first two didn't work, but the double quote did work. I also edited the tags.